# WPF ListBox ErrorTemplate

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, listbox, errortemplate

In my WPF application I've a ListBox binding to a collection of view models.
Those view models support validation by implement INotifyDataErrorInfo.
I’m trying to display an error template for items with validation errors in my ListBox.

I’m able to get the ListBox to display the default error template by setting *NotifyOnValidationError=True* on the ItemSource binding of the ListBox.
Which looks like this:
[image]

Code of my ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxEvents" ItemsSource="{Binding Events, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource EventListTemplate}"></ListBox>
```

My ListBox style:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxValidationError">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border Background="Red" Margin="5">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowTitleBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxValidationError}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

The ListBox item template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EventListTemplate" DataType="{x:Type event:EventViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringConverter}, ConverterParameter='-'}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontStyle="Italic" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource ItemDeleteButton}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I display a custom error template for my ListBoxItems?
(My goal is to make the background of the items red)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `Valdiation.ErrorTemplate` on ListBoxItem as well in `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Red" Opacity="0.2">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

---

Most likely you want to show it on ListBoxItem when any property in item throws an error. Say Name property in ListBoxItem data is invalid which is bind to TextBox. Set `ValidatesOnDataErrors` to true on textbox and set `Validation.ValidationAdornerSite` to parent ListBoxItem.

For sample:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                     Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Red" Opacity="0.2">
                           <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Your solution works, but only if the property on which the TextBox binds has any validation errors. How can I display the validation ErrorTemplate when any property of the ListBoxItems DataContext has validation errors?